# Analyzed field in kibna

Tags: elastic-stack

i need help to correct kibana field. when I try to visualizing the fields, it shows me the following warning:

Careful! The field selected contains analyzed strings. Analyzed strings are highly unique and can use a lot of memory to visualize. Values such as foo-bar will be broken into foo and bar. See Mapping Types for more information on setting this field as not_analyzed

Answer (score 0):

you should read [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/fielddata.html), [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html) and [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html) to better understand what's going on.

In brief: you  can have analyzed or not_analyzed string fields. When using aggregations with analyzed fields, elasticsearch uses fielddata which can consume much memory, as stated in the warning.

To solve this you should set a mapping or a template for your index, or use logstash which should use a default template to have both analyzed and not anlyzed fields.